# Are US wizards all pure blood since they don't have any kind of relationship with Muggles?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

From what we find out in *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, wizards in the U.S. are not allowed to even be friends with Muggles, let alone to marry them. So does it mean every wizard in the U.S. is pure-blooded, since magical people are only allowed to have relationships with magical people?

Comment: All "pure bloods" have inter-married and interbred with muggles for millennia. The idea of pure-bloodedness is a myth.

Comment: You might ask whether they're considered pure-bloods by those who care about such things...

Comment: Just because people are not allowed to do something doesn't mean they haven't done it.

Comment: just because it was against the law doesn't mean they don't exist. even in UK, they have statute of secrecy and yet half bloods and muggle borns exist. since fantastic beasts is set in a prequel, it is safe to assume that more no-mag friendly laws might have come up along the years.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The opposite is true:

From JK Rowling's '[History of Magic in North America](https://www.pottermore.com/collection-episodic/history-of-magic-in-north-america-en)'

> There is a far higher percentage of No-Maj-born witches and wizards in the New World than elsewhere. While these witches and wizards often went on to marry and found their own all-magical families, the pure-blood ideology that has dogged much of Europe’s magical history has gained far less traction in America."

Those that did follow the pure-blood idea rarely went anywhere near America because of the adversity facing them and the general wizarding population was lower. But wizardry will not be stopped it seems - it was manifested in a high proportion of Muggle/No-Maj-born wizards.

I suppose families like the Goldsteins (who seems to be all magical) just don't see themselves as pure-blood. They would likely marry from a limited but still fairly broad selection - people met at work, school or through owl-post dating (which I just made up).

Comment: +1 for owl-post dating. "You can't wait to see WHO you'll meet next."

Comment: Horny wizards need the help of a tawny owl?